# Rails stimulus one form change for many urls and turbo frames

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-7, stimulusjs

I am building a dashboard with multiple elements like charts, tables, simple fields with calculated values etc and I want to use Rails7 with stimulus.

In the past I used jQuery so I just created empty elements and then called several ajax requests in paralel to get data for every elements and populate it. So initial page load was super fast and then it loaded all necessary data. Dashboard had few dropdowns options to change data and when I loaded page I just sent defaults. Every dropdown change reloaded all data for all elements by filter used in dropdown.

How to do similar approach with stimulus?
When I use turbo form what I can do is submit form on page load, but it looks ugly (page initially loads and instantly reloads). And if I have many elements it gets slow because it first needs to finish all calculations.

this is my simple filter with 2 dropdowns

```
<%= form_with url: "", method: :get, data: { controller: "home", home_target: "form", turbo_frame: "home_dashboard", turbo_action: "advance" } do |form| %>
<div class="row">
<div class="d-sm-flex align-items-center mb-3">
    <div class="col-lg-2" >

<%= form.select :city, options_for_select(City.all.pluck(:name,:id)), {include_blank: (t 'all')}, {class: 'form-select', data: {action: "input->home#search"}} %>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-2" >

<%= form.select :year, options_for_select(@years.reverse, (params[:year] || Date.today.year)), {selected: params[:year], include_blank:false}, {class: 'form-select', data: {action: "input->home#search"}} %>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

and this is my home controller in stimulus which is simple

```
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"

// Connects to data-controller="home"
export default class extends Controller {
  connect() {
  }

  static targets = ["form"]

  connect() {
    this.formTarget.requestSubmit()
  }
    
    search() {
     this.formTarget.requestSubmit()
    }

}
```

my rails controller gets ugly big because I am calculating lot of fields dynamically and showing them in turbo frame tag...this is just a part of data I want to show so there should be much more

```
<%= turbo_frame_tag "home_dashboard" do %>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xl-6">
<div class="card border-0 mb-3 overflow-hidden ">
<div class="card-body">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xl-7 col-lg-8">
<div class="mb-3 fs-13px">
<b><%= (t 'invoices.invoiced').upcase %></b>
</div>

<div class="d-flex mb-1">
    <% if @invoices_sumed.present? %>
<h2 class="mb-0"><span data-animation="number" data-value="<%= @invoices_sumed[0][1] %>"><%= @invoices_sumed[0][1] %></span> <%= @invoices_sumed[0][0]  %></h2>
<% else %>
<h2 class="mb-0"><span data-animation="number" data-value="0">0</span> EUR</h2>
<% end %>
</div>
<div class="mb-3">
<i class="fa fa-caret-up"></i> <span data-animation="number" data-value="<%=  @invoices_sumed_compare %>"><%=  @invoices_sumed_compare %></span>% <%= t 'invoices.compared_previous_year' %>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="row text-truncate">

<div class="col-6">
<div class=""><%= t 'invoices.total' %></div>
<div class="fs-18px mb-5px fw-bold" data-animation="number" data-value="<%= @invoices.size %>"><%= @invoices.size %></div>
<div class="progress h-5px rounded-3  mb-5px">
<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped rounded-right " data-animation="width" data-value="<%= calc_year_ratio(@invoices.size,@invoices_total_size) %>%" style="width: <%= calc_year_ratio(@invoices.size,@invoices_total_size) %>%;"></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-6">
<div class=""><%= t 'invoices.average' %> <small>(<%= (t 'invoices.median').to_s + ":" %> <strong><%= "#{@invoices_median_value.round(2)} #{@invoices_top_currency}"  %></strong>)</small></div>
<div class="fs-18px mb-5px fw-bold"><span data-animation="number" data-value="<%= @invoices_avg_value.round(2) %>"><%= @invoices_avg_value.round(2) %></span> <%= @invoices_top_currency %></div>
<div class="progress h-5px rounded-3  mb-5px">
<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped rounded-right bg-orange" data-animation="width" data-value="<%= calc_median_total_ratio(@invoices_avg_value,@invoices_max_value) %>%" style="width: <%= calc_median_total_ratio(@invoices_avg_value,@invoices_max_value) %>%;"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

</div>


<div class="col-xl-5 col-lg-4 align-items-center d-flex justify-content-center">
<canvas
  data-controller="chart"
  data-chart-data-value='<%= @chart_total.to_json %>'
  data-chart-options-value="<%= @chart_options.to_json %>"
></canvas>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
    </div>
<div class="col-xl-4">
    <div class="table-responsive">
         <table id="contractors"  class="table table-hover align-middle" style="width:100%;">
            <thead></thead>
            <tbody>
                <% @contractors.each do |contractor| %>
                <tr>
                    <td><%= contractor[0]%></td>
                    <td><%= contractor[2]%></td>
                </tr>
                <% end %>
            </tbody>
         </table>
    </div>
</div>

</div>
<% end %>
```

is there any way how to split this in multiple turbo frames with multiple urls to call with one form select change?

Comment: Break the content of this big turbo frame into many turbo frames that matches your former jQuery request. And add a `src` arg so that it fetches the content from the back independently. You can also programmatically set the source of a turbo frame and force reload it whenever you want.

Comment: Also you don't mention any form in the Ajax method. Though you can use Turbo stream to populate multiple Turbo Frames after the form has been sent, but it is no longer concurrent as with multiple requests / Ajax calls..

Comment: @Maxence thanks I split my big turbo frames into multiple small frames with src attribute and now in stimulus I call frame reload with new src including updated params as I was not able to refresh it with form submit (many turbo frames, one form)